# What version of the song "Don't Die" is used in "The Imperfects"?

Tags: soundtrack, the-imperfects

In the first and last episodes of season 1 of *The Imperfects*, Tilda's character is introduced and said goodbye to with the song "Don't Die" by the band NOBRO in the background.

However, you can tell from the singer's intonation that this is a different version of the song than the version on NOBRO's album, "Sick Hustle".

Is this different version also by NOBRO? Is it a cover? My first guess is that this is a cover recorded by and for The Imperfects show, perhaps with Morgan Taylor Campbell—the actress playing Tilda—singing. Anyone know?

If you want to check for yourself, the song is played at about 1:26 of S1:E1

Comment: [**Who is the real band that Tilda covers?**](https://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2022/09/08/the-imperfects-soundtrack-songs-music-track-list-netflix/): *The real band that Tilda covers in The Imperfects are NOBRO. In the opening episode of the series, we see Tilda performing with a band known as the Itchy Nipples. However, the punk rock group are only fictional and Morgan Taylor Campbell is not actually performing an original song. Instead, the band are covering NOBRO’s tracks Don’t Die and Til I Get It All which feature on their 2020 EP, Sick Hustle.* -

Comment: I listened to the version in the show again and her talking definitely doesn't match the talking in the NOBRO music video or Sick Hustle EP. It's some different version. The inflection is different.